# Lotus Notes reply to all only lists the first person in the "to" section

Tags: lotus-notes

Why does Lotus Notes only reply to the first person in the e-mail list on a reply to all and put everyone else in the cc section?
Thanks

Comment: Because that is how it is coded... code is open, its up to you to change this behaviour, if you want to have it a different way..

Answer (score 0):

Lotus Notes has been around for about 30 years. It was one of the very first email products aimed at networks of business PC users, and it built up considerable market share. IBM bought Lotus because it was the market leader in the middle of the 1990s. The Lotus team devoted a lot of effort to studying what people in their business market wanted email to do. One of the early conclusions that just about everybody agreed on was that reply-to-all was a convenient feature but a widely-abused feature.

One of the overall goals of many Lotus Notes customers was to minimize the use of email! Yes, you read that right. While Lotus Notes is, of course, an email product, it is much more than an email product. Customers wanted users to minimize their use of email and do as much of their collaboration as possible using custom Notes applications. And when users did use email, customers wanted to keep reply-to-all blasts under control.

Putting everyone except the sender of the message that was being replied to into the CC list was, I believe, a purposeful decision intended to give users a hint that they should edit down too-long recipient lists before pressing 'Send'.